# What is children parameter in this react-redux to-do example?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn react by reading a basic tutorial. The official redux tutorial:
I have almost figured out how components are passed down through connect method.

A little thing that I could not understand: in the following Link.js file, where does the argument 'children' is being passed on from.

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#componentslinkjs

Because this Link.js is being used only by Filterlink.js. and through mapStateToProps it passes the 'active' parameter and the mapDisoatchToProps passes the Onclick function.

Where does this component get the children parameter from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use FilterLink like this:

```
<FilterLink><span>hello<span></FilterLink>
```

Then the `active` and `onClick` is passed from redux's connect and the `children` is the `<span>hello<span>`.

The `connect` just create a wrapper component on the `Link`, and any props on the wrapper is passed through to the underlying component.

Comment: but AFAIK we need `this.props.children` to access children? or `React.children`. How can we directly access the children this way, and in this context?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. The connect just take the children props and pass it down. The Link is a function component that take the props as its parameters and return a React.Element.